# Eslint no-unused-var for decorator factory

Tags: javascript, eslint, babel-eslint

Thanks for browsing my question.
I met some eslint errors after using decorator like this

```
@decorate({ title: 'head' })
class Test {
  @decorate(item => ({ age: item.age }))
  method(){
    return ;
  }
}
export default Test;
```

.eslintrc config :

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": 2
  }
}
```

pacakges version

```
"babel-eslint": "6.0.3",
"eslint": "^2.8.0"
```

eslint error message

```
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  at collectUnusedVariables (/Users/Documents/support_decorator/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:184:44)
```

Looks like this line causes problem. And used ES5 common anonymous function, errors still exist.

```
@decorate(item => ({ age: item.age }))
```

What should i do? Upgrade eslint and babel-eslint to specific version or just close "no-unused-vars" rule?

Answer (score 1):

This is [fixed in eslint v6.0.4](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/281), just upgrade.

Comment: Perhaps you mean babel-eslint?
Thanks a lot, I did search in babel-ealint issues, but got nothing. hah